# How can I set an expiration time for a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I would like to show a `UILocalNotification`, but it will only be valid for 24 hours. At the end of 24 hours, I want the notification to "expire"; that is: the user can no longer see the obsolete notification. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm referring to a notification that has already fired.

I believe that setting the badge to zero will clear out existing notifications. I will try to see whether this also clears local notifications (in addition to push notifications).

Answer (score 2):

To cancel already delivered notifications use

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["myidentifier"])`

or

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

Example code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45218609/2650588

Comment: Can this be executed when the app is not in the foreground and the user has not interacted with the notification?

Comment: @Roboris, notification center is a shared instance, you can put this line in any piece of code, which can be called while app is not in foreground. There are many ways of waking up the app and making it do work in background (without making it appear to user). Like pushing a remote notification or "clicking" a link. You choose the proper way that fits your needs.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this? "waking up the app and making it do work in background". My use case scenario is purely local (not remote). More like a custom calendar/timer app which sends multiple notifications before each event, ideal for procrastinators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIApplication.scheduledLocalNotifications to get a list of your pending notifications and then cancel the ones you want to get rid of.

Comment: Can this be executed when the app is not in the foreground and the user has not interacted with the notification?